# Result getting double when running query with join

Tags: mysql, join

I am using this query to fetch the data from 3 tables.

```
SELECT sum( tu.filesize ) AS totalSize, tu.sender, tu.receiver, tu.valid_time, group_concat( tu.filename ) AS files, tu.file_path, us.uid temp_id, tu.unique_key, tu.uid user_id, tu.file_encryption, t_l.encryption_password
FROM tbl_uploads tu
LEFT JOIN tbl_users us ON us.id = tu.uid
LEFT JOIN tbl_logs t_l ON t_l.u_key = tu.unique_key
WHERE date( tu.valid_time ) = '2014-01-09'
AND tu.sender <> ''
GROUP BY tu.unique_key
```

But not getting the expected result, because `tbl_uploads` and `tbl_logs` has almost the same field with the name `filesize, filename` so when i run this query i got the double filesize `462804` and files; filesize should be `231402`

Comment: I don't think it's because of the similar field in tbl_logs. You are probably getting the rows in tbl_uploads more than once because there are multiple rows in tlb_logs which relate to one row in tbl_uploads.

Comment: @Rembunator yes there is multiple rows in `tbl_logs` as well, same like `tbl_uploads` but in `tbl_uploads` i have used group by to make the result in single row but group by tbl_logs not working as well, i tried also. like `GROUP BY tu.unique_key, t_l.u_key`

Answer (score 0):

To avoid double rows from tbl_logs try:

```
SELECT sum( tu.filesize ) AS totalSize, tu.sender, tu.receiver, tu.valid_time, group_concat( tu.filename ) AS files, tu.file_path, us.uid temp_id, tu.unique_key, tu.uid user_id, tu.file_encryption, t_l.encryption_password
FROM tbl_uploads tu
    LEFT JOIN tbl_users us ON us.id = tu.uid
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT u_key, encryption_password FROM tbl_logs GROUP BY u_key, encryption_password) AS t_l ON t_l.u_key = tu.unique_key
WHERE date( tu.valid_time ) = '2014-01-09'
AND tu.sender <> ''
GROUP BY tu.unique_key
```

Comment: You could instead make a view of tbl_logs with grouping and join this view. But you will get arbitrary rows from the log table which might not be what you want. It looks to me like you might need to reconsider your database structure. If arbitrary rows aren't a concern, you'll probably have the same data in multiple rows which doesn't seem like a good idea to me.